# Find sequence $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I have spent almost 2 hrs on this question, but I couldn’t find any good example for this one. The question is:
Find sequence $(a_n)$ and $(b_n)$ satisifying:
a) $a_n>0$, and $a_n \rightarrow0$;
b) The partial sum of $b_n$ is a bounded sequence; and,
c) $\sum a_nb_n$ diverges.

I felt like if this problem is somehow impossible, as for me, the conditions are exactly that of Abel’s test except that $a_n$ need not be decreasing. I need help on this one....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take$$a_n=\begin{cases}\frac1n&\text{ if $n$ is odd}\\\frac1{n^2}&\text{ otherwise}\end{cases}$$and $b_n=(-1)^n$.

Comment: (+1) This works because the sequence $a_n$ is not of bounded variation (and therefore, is not the difference of two monotonic sequences).